# Boolean was amount ever greater than x?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Interesting question for you all. Here's a sample of my dataset (see below). I have warehouses, dates, and the ***change*** in inventory level at that specific date for a given warehouse.

Ex: Assuming 1/1/2018 is first date, warehouse 1 starts out with 100 in inventory, then 600, then 300, then 500...etc.

My question I'd like to answer in SQL: By warehouse ID, did each warehouse ever have inventory of more than 750 (yes/no)?

I can't sum the entire column, because the ending inventory (sum of column by warehouse) is likely lower than a past inventory level. Any help is appreciated!!

```
+--------------+------------+---------------+
| Warehouse_id |    Date    | Inventory_Amt |
+--------------+------------+---------------+
|            1 | 1/1/2018   | +100          |
|            1 | 6/1/2018   | +500          |
|            1 | 6/15/2018  | -300          |
|            1 | 7/1/2018   | +200          |
|            1 | 8/1/2018   | -400          |
|            1 | 12/15/2018 | +100          |
|            2 | 1/1/2018   | +10           |
|            2 | 6/1/2018   | +50           |
|            2 | 6/15/2018  | -30           |
|            2 | 7/1/2018   | +20           |
|            2 | 8/1/2018   | -40           |
|            2 | 12/15/2018 | +10           |
|            3 | 1/1/2018   | +100          |
|            3 | 6/1/2018   | +500          |
|            4 | 6/15/2018  | +300          |
|            4 | 7/1/2018   | +200          |
|            4 | 8/1/2018   | -400          |
|            4 | 12/15/2018 | +100          |
+--------------+------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum and then filtering:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*, sum(inventory_amt) over (partition by warehouse_id order by date) as inventory
      from inventory i
     ) i
where inventory_amt > 750
```

Comment: Does this calculate the sum of the entire columnn by warehouse_id? If so, I need something a bit different. Since these warehouse inventory amounts aren't cumulative, there's a chance the ending inventory is below 750 when an earlier inventory level was above 750. Another concern...I don't think this works for a proc sql; statement. I'm trying to run it in SQL Server. Thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Do I need something like: ...over (partition by warehouse_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row)...?

Comment: @tubaguy . . . Of course you can use window functions in stored procedures.  This does a cumulative sum and the window range clause is not needed in most databases.